# enviar valor de temp_var_node para a base de dados MySQL

Tags: python-3.x

Pretendo enviar o valor da temperatura em OPCUA para a base de dados MySQL, neste caso o valor de temp_var_node, o meu código é o seguinte:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "..")
import time
import datetime
import subprocess
import logging

from opcua import Server
import BMP085
import mysql.connector as mysql

##### Sensor Data of BMP180 ######################
bmp = BMP085.BMP085()
temperature =bmp.read_temperature()
altitude = bmp.read_altitude()
pressure = bmp.read_pressure()
################################################

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level = logging.WARNING)

# get Objects node, this is where we should put our nodes
# setup our server
server = Server()
server.set_endpoint("opc.tcp://192.168.1.10:4840/freeopcua/server/")

# setup our own namespace, not really necessary but should as spec
uri = "http://192.168.1.10:4840/freeopcua/server/"
idx = server.register_namespace(uri)

# get Objects node, this is where we should put our nodes
objects = server.get_objects_node()

# populating our address space
################################### Object ####################################################
sensordata = objects.add_object(idx, "Sensor One BMP180")
############################# Variables of Object #############################################
temp_var_node= sensordata.add_variable(idx, "Temperature Sensor One", temperature)
print("the temp_var_node is:", temp_var_node)
altit_var_node = sensordata.add_variable(idx, "Altitude Sensor One", altitude)
print("the altit_var_node is:", altit_var_node)
press_var_node = sensordata.add_variable(idx, "Pressure Sensor One", pressure)
print("the pressure_var_node is:", press_var_node)
#################### Set MyVariable to be writable by clients #################################

temp_var_node.set_writable()# Set MyVariable to be writable by clients
altit_var_node.set_writable()
press_var_node.set_writable()

######################### Sending data values of variables to the database ####################################

db = mysql.connect(host = '192.168.1.15',port = 3306,user = 'root',password = 'admin',database = 'OPCUA')
cursor = db.cursor()
delete = "DROP TABLE sensorBMP180_raspberrypi2"
cursor.execute(delete)

sql = """CREATE TABLE sensorBMP180_raspberrypi2 (
         temperature DOUBLE,
         altitude DOUBLE,
         pressure INT)"""
cursor.execute(sql)

# starting de server OPCUA!
server.start()
try:

    while True:
 ############## Values on UaExpert ###########################################     
        temp_var_node.set_value(bmp.read_temperature())
        time.sleep(2)   
        altit_var_node.set_value(bmp.read_altitude())
        time.sleep(2)
        press_var_node.set_value(bmp.read_pressure())
        time.sleep(2)
################## Values to DataBase #########################################
        temperature = bmp.read_temperature()
        pressure = bmp.read_pressure()
        altitude = bmp.read_altitude()
        time.sleep(2)
        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO sensorBMP180_raspberrypi2 VALUES (%s, %s, %s)""",(temperature,pressure,altitude))
        db.commit()

finally:

    #close connection, remove subcsriptions, etc
    server.stop()
    db.close()
#################################################################################
```

Quando na linha

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO sensorBMP180_raspberrypi2 VALUES (%s, %s, %s)""",(temperature,pressure,altitude))
```

altero para temp_var_node, press_var_node e altit_var_node em que estas são os valores dos nodes dá-me este erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

############################# código para obter os valores das variáveis dos node

```
       temp = temp_var_node.get_value()
       print("the temp_var_node is:", temp)
       time.sleep(1)
       altit = altit_var_node.get_value()
       print("the altit_var_node is:", altit)
       time.sleep(1)
       press = press_var_node.get_value()
       print("the pressure_var_node is:", press)
       time.sleep(1)

       cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO sensorBMP180_raspberrypi1 VALUES (%s, %s, %s)""",(temp, altit, press))
       db.commit()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual o tipo de `temperature, pressure` e `altitude`?

Comment: temperature é double, pressure é int e altitude é double

Comment: Na sua tabela `altitude` é `INT`...

Comment: E pelo erro, o valor que está jogando nas variáveis é do tipo `node`, tenta converter explicitamente quando for inserir no banco e me fala o resultado.

Comment: Algo assim: `cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO sensorBMP180_raspberrypi2 VALUES (%s, %s, %s)""",(float(temperature),int(pressure),int(altitude)))`

Comment: Eu fiz assim para obter os valores dos nodes (ver na pergunta acima o codigo que fiz)

Comment: Dá uma olhada na resposta, acho que não entendeu o comentário ;)

Comment: como está no seu comentário deu a imagem acima, e como poderei converter as variáveis de node ex. temp_var_node?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81821/discussion-between-tuxpilgrim-and-sergio-nunes).

Answer (score 2):

Vamos analisar as saídas de erro, por partes.

A primeira saída de erro diz:

> `AttributeError: 'MySQLConverter' object has no attribute '_node_to_mysql'`

E a segunda:

> `TypeError: Python 'node' cannot be converted to a MySQL type`

Isso sugere que ao invés de estar passando as variáveis como estão na sua tabela no banco, está passando com o tipo `node`, nessas atribuições:

```
    temperature = bmp.read_temperature() -> está indo node e não double
    pressure = bmp.read_pressure() --> está indo node e não int
    altitude = bmp.read_altitude() --> está indo node e não double
```

O que poderia ser facilmente corrigido fazendo a conversão para o tipo que quer:

```
        temperature = float(bmp.read_temperature()) 
        pressure = int(bmp.read_pressure()) 
        altitude = float(bmp.read_altitude())
```

Assim você não vai problemas na conversão para o tipo da sua tabela.

**Adendo:** Na [doc](https://learn.adafruit.com/using-the-bmp085-with-raspberry-pi/using-the-adafruit-bmp085-python-library) da *Adafruit BMP085* você tem um exemplo parecido, onde para exibir com o `print` é feita a conversão.

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiz a conversão das variaveis temp_var_node, altit_var_node e press_var_node desta forma:

```
       temp = temp_var_node.get_value()
       print("the temp_var_node is:", temp)
       time.sleep(1)
       altit = altit_var_node.get_value()
       print("the altit_var_node is:", altit)
       time.sleep(1)
       press = press_var_node.get_value()
       print("the pressure_var_node is:", press)
       time.sleep(1)

       cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO sensorBMP180_raspberrypi1 VALUES (%s, %s, %s)""",(float(temp), float(altit), int(press)))
       db.commit()
```

e dá isto :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Está bem convertido?

Comment: Isso era o resultado esperado dos seus testes?

Answer (score 0):

Sim pois no UaExpert da Unified Automation também tem esses valores como se pode ver na imagem, ou seja, queria obter o  Value dos NodesID

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

só não estou a conseguir passar para a base de dados o Node Id e o data type, mas o Value passa